# How do I use Bakoma fonts in my text?

Tags: fonts, computer-modern, bakoma

I find the information on Computer Modern and Bakoma fonts confusing. I really want to change font and see what I get. How do I change my font to Bakoma?

These are the fonts I want: [Bakoma Computer Modern](http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/fonts/bakoma-fontnames.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the fonts in your local font tree and use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

then they will be used by default.

Herbert